# How can I download Flash videos from videolecture.com with a Mac?

Tags: mac, flash, streaming, grab, rtmp

I would like to download this video: http://videolectures.net/mlss07_rasmussen_bigp/. But I cannot do it. How can I do it?

Of course the platform is Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out this article: http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20070420014456930 which outlines a method of downloading the video via Safari.

It specifies YouTube, but as far as I know it should work for any web video.

Comment: It works for other web players.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the Safari method won't work for such streams. But you may use [Jaksta for Mac](http://www.jaksta.com/download-video-for-mac/) for downloading online videos.

Answer (score 1):

I have found great success with [ANT Video Downloader](http://www.ant.com/video-downloader) to download streaming video.  It is a free Firefox extension.

Comment: I don't think ANT works with videolectures.net videos. Did you try?

Comment: I have not tried it with videolectures.net